# Getting on-phone iPhone / Android contacts via PHP Web App / Facebook Deep Linking Workaround

Tags: php, facebook, web-applications, mobile, deep-linking

Here's the situation. I'm working on a PHP-based web app for a company with a desire to setup an SMS share widget on their mobile site. The goal is to allow visitors to mass-share via SMS to their list of mobile contacts, in much the same way that Cloudsponge does this for e-mail contacts via the Google/Hotmail/Yahoo/Exchange APIs.

I was told repeatedly that this is impossible, but after a bit of research we've come across the possibility of accomplishing this via the Facebook deep integration built into newer smartphones and mobile devices.

SO, being completely inept, and coming into this with zero knowledge of how I might accomplish this... and having spent hours researching Google turning up very little / misleading information, I come to you. Where to look? What to do? Not looking for a blueprint here... just a hand (or two, or three :-) to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You are creating a microsite (just html / js / css) that will open in mobile browser and you want to access the mobile's address book?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Why not?

Comment: I'm really surprised at the lack of response to this. Is this really so complex that nobody even has a clue?

Comment: Did you get any help towards this? I came across the same kind of idea, that how it would be if I do have all the contacts of my mobile to my web page once I verify the process of mobile number I entered I own.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access any system feature (GPS fine location, Contacts, Câmera) from a web app running in a mobile browser. Just for security reasons.